# Modern, Cross-Platform Game Engine with Requirements

Tags: gratis, game-development

I'm looking for a basic game/graphics library (either is fine) in any language, preferably C++ or C#. I would like it to be more high level (think more like MonoGame/XNA as opposed to Vulkan or DirectX). There's also some other requirements that would be nice:

*Note: I'm aware this might not exist fully, so anything that is even close would be great. I'm just looking for something that supports more modern machine, and learning it will be at least somewhat useful in a few years.*

#### Requirements

- Cross-platform (Windows 7+, macOS, most Linux distros)
- High DPI support

  *Note that as long as the library can tell me the pixel-density of the screen, that's fine. This is mostly for 2D rendering, as 3D doesn't makes sense for high DPI*
- Modern, ie. newer and probably going to still be around/in real environments in a few years

---

I'm aware of Unity, which I think meets all these requirements, but I'm looking for a programming library, not really a full system like that.